# Rubocop error: "Use attr_reader to define trivial reader methods."

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I am having some struggle using rubocop and don't know how I could solve this problem.

The code I have:

```
class Test
  @hello = 'stackoverflow'

  def self.hello
    @hello
  end
end

p Test.hello
```

It runs the way i want, but when I run rubocop it says to use attr_reader. If I try to use attr_reader it gives me NoMethodError.

I already tried to solve this like this, but rubocop is still not happy.

```
class Test2
  @hello = 'stackoverflow'

  class << self
    def hello
      @hello
    end
  end
end
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `attr_reader` on singleton class so it adds "hello" method to your Test singleton class.

```
class Test
  @hello = 'stackoverflow'

  class << self
    attr_reader :hello
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you it seems to work fine. But I got a new problem, that my method and field names are different.

Comment: if your method and instance variable names are different rubocop should not complain with your initial implementation.